# Pushed you on a swing

Tags: grammar

Push someone on a swing makes sense, but saying "He pushed you on a swing" doesn't make sense, right? I still see people use that phrase, but it doesn't make sense, because "on a swing" complements "someone", correct? Or is "you" like any other pronoun like "her" or noun like "someone"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, "I pushed you on a swing" is fine.

When you say, "I pushed someone on a swing," the phrase "on a swing" can, grammatically speaking, modify either "pushed" or "someone." The first interpretation is more likely (you helped someone to swing, but you're not specifying who the person is) than is the second (you went up to someone on a swing and started pushing them).